# Laravel - Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in where clause is ambiguous in Laravel Filter

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 5.8 to filter by date and name. While I clicked on search, I got this error:

> "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `services` inner join `cloudsubscriptions` on `services`.`name` = `cloudsubscriptions`.`service_name` where `created_at` between 2019-05-31 and 2019-06-29 and `name` like %Learnersway% group by DATE(cloudsubscriptions.created_at), `services`.`id`, `services`.`name`) ◀"

Here is my code:

```
public function revenueReport(Request $request)
{
$data['title'] = 'Revenue Report';

$revenuereports = DB::table('cloudsubscriptions as c')
 ->select(
       'c.service_name', 
        DB::raw('COUNT(*) as total_users'), 
        DB::raw('SUM(c.amount) as total_amount'),
        DB::raw('DATE(c.created_at)as subscription_date') 
  ) 
 ->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE(c.created_at)'), 'service_name')                                                          
 ->orderByRaw('c.created_at DESC');

    $render=[];
    if(isset($request->start_date) && isset($request->end_date))
    {
        $revenuereports=$revenuereports->whereBetween('created_at',[$request->start_date,$request->end_date]);
        //$revenuedetails=$revenuedetails->whereBetween(date('users.created_at'),[$request->start_date,$request->end_date]);
        $render['start_date']=$request->start_date;
        $render['end_date']=$request->end_date;
    }elseif(isset($request->start_date))
    {
        $revenuereports=$revenuereports->where('created_at',$request->start_date);

        $render['start_date']=$request->start_date;
    }        
    if(isset($request->service_name))
    {
        $revenuereports=$revenuereports->where('service_name','like','%'.$request->service_name.'%');
        $render['service_name']=$request->service_name;
    }

    //dd($revenuedetails->toSql());
    $revenuereports= $revenuereports->orderBy('created_at','DESC');
    $revenuereports= $revenuereports->paginate(15);
    $revenuereports= $revenuereports->appends($render);
    $data['revenuereports'] = $revenuereports;

return view('report.revenueReport',$data);
}
```

Comment: `$revenuereports=$revenuereports->whereBetween('c.created_at', [$request->start_date, $request->end_date]);`

`$revenuereports=$revenuereports->where('created_at',$request->start_date);`

Changing $revenuereports where value in your if and elseif condition body
?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

specify from which table for example c.created_at or users.created_at

Answer (score 1):

in your code you haven't specified which table created_at you want the filter so the issue is coming.

to solve issue you need to specify a created_at column with the table name.

Update to the following code, it will work.

```
public function revenueReport(Request $request)
{
$data['title'] = 'Revenue Report';

$revenuereports = DB::table('cloudsubscriptions as c')
 ->select(
       'c.service_name', 
        DB::raw('COUNT(*) as total_users'), 
        DB::raw('SUM(c.amount) as total_amount'),
        DB::raw('DATE(c.created_at)as subscription_date') 
  ) 
 ->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE(c.created_at)'), 'service_name')                                                          
 ->orderByRaw('c.created_at DESC');

    $render=[];
    if(isset($request->start_date) && isset($request->end_date))
    {
        $revenuereports=$revenuereports->whereBetween('subscription_date',[$request->start_date,$request->end_date]);
        //$revenuedetails=$revenuedetails->whereBetween(date('users.created_at'),[$request->start_date,$request->end_date]);
        $render['start_date']=$request->start_date;
        $render['end_date']=$request->end_date;
    }elseif(isset($request->start_date))
    {
        $revenuereports=$revenuereports->where('subscription_date',$request->start_date);

        $render['start_date']=$request->start_date;
    }        
    if(isset($request->service_name))
    {
        $revenuereports=$revenuereports->where('service_name','like','%'.$request->service_name.'%');
        $render['service_name']=$request->service_name;
    }

    //dd($revenuedetails->toSql());
    $revenuereports= $revenuereports->orderBy('subscription_date','DESC');
    $revenuereports= $revenuereports->paginate(15);
    $revenuereports= $revenuereports->appends($render);
    $data['revenuereports'] = $revenuereports;

return view('report.revenueReport',$data);
}
```